# How to create multi-color text border in css3

Tags: css, border

How to create multi-color text border or underline in css3 as bellow :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this!

```css
  

   

.box {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 75%, blue 0) bottom/100% 4px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
   <div class="box">Latest articles</div>
```

Comment: @SaadBhutto the pseudo element is useless https://jsfiddle.net/kestqj9f/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 3px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```